# Responsive images on wordpress website

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hoping you could help me with my problem. Please kindly visit [www.expandedpolystyrene.co.za](http://www.expandedpolystyrene.co.za) the footer image is not responsive, so if the broswer window is made smaller to mobile size,the text within the footer goes over the footer image.

Also, if you click on the products page, the header banner with the search bar in it has the same problem (.small_banner). Is there a way to make these 2 images responsive? Also, in the front page.. If you reduce it to a mobile size, it adds an extra green band on top of the slider banner. Will you be able to take it out? Please help

Comment: could you add your fiddle to showcase your code

Comment: Sorry, Im new here. How do I do that?

Comment: jsfiddle.net where you can edit

Comment: sorry, I do not know how to work with jsfiddle. Also. I dont know which part of the jsquery is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to make images responsive is to add `max-width: 100%;` – that will make them scale when there is not enough space.

Also, I would suggest you to rebuild your website as it's a real mess. For example, there is no need for those images with text in footer: it could be done by plane html text.

Comment: Yes, it is a real mess. I'm just a junior so I still have quite alot to learn. How would I do that by using HTML?

Comment: http://expandedpolystyrene.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/text.png this is a simple text, get the font name from the designer (or try to find by yourself) and make it a html text

Comment: what about the one with the images?

Comment: Just try to describe what do you need and how'd you expect the images to behave. Or, go back to html/css lessons and try to recreate the whole site (or, if you don't have time, try to recreate only the footer, for example in jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

Your image is a background image.

Try using background-size:cover; in your css for that image.

```
background-size:cover;
```